# Using binary variables to linearize a non-linear constraint in LPP

Tags: linear-programming

I have a constraint that makes the optimization problem nonlinear. The constraint of interest is:

```
If (a-b)>=0
    then c=(a-b)
else
    c=0
```

where $a$, $b$ and $c$ are variables. How to linearize this constraint to convert the problem to linear form?

Comment: https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/linearization

Comment: I would call that *piecewise affine* rather than nonlinear.

Answer (score 0):

In other words, you want $c=\max(a-b,0)$.  If $c$ appears in the objective as minimization, you can relax to $c\ge\max(a-b,0)$, which is enforced by linear constraints $c\ge a-b$ and $c \ge 0$.

Comment: Max function will make it non-linear only. What we want is a linearized form of the function in LINGO. We don't know how to use binary variables as both a and b are variables.

Comment: My answer suggests replacing the $\max$ constraint with two linear constraints.